# Why do the critical exponents at the Gaussian fixed point coincide with mean field theory?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, renormalization, ising-model

In the Ising model, we know that in dimensions higher than the upper critical dimension, $d_u=4$, the critical exponents can be found from mean field theory. We also know that for the same dimensions, we flow to the Gaussian fixed point in RG flow.

This seems like an important result, also replicated in $d=4$ - that above the critical dimension, we flow under RG to the Gaussian fixed point, and the mean field theory critical exponents agree with those found at the Gaussian fixed point. Indeed, [Tong](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/sft/sft.pdf) says this behaviour is 'no coincidence' in section 3.3.1.

However, I can't see why this should be the case. In mean field theory, we ignore fluctuations, so don't care about gradient terms such as $(\nabla \phi)^2$ in the free energy. At the Gaussian fixed point, we ignore terms like $\phi^4$, $\phi^6$. So why should the critical exponents in MFT and at the Gaussian fixed point agree?

Comment: Why would the kinetic term $(\nabla \phi)^2$ be neglected in the free energy/ path integral when dealing with mean field theory?